# Google Translate does not translate URL

Tags: google-translate

As seen in the screenshot below, when I paste an URL into Google Translate, the translated version is just... the URL.

I would expect it to translate the web page that can be found at that URL. How to do that?

[image: Google Translate does not translate URL]

Comment: Even though it says "Type text or a website address".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click the url and you'll see that the page content has been translated.

Comment: or just hit 'enter' after typing or copy/paste of your url